# How to style the "option" value in select dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stylize `option` tags in this `select` box, but when I click on it option tags are wider than the select box, but they should be equal. Is it possible to make it happen via css?

Here's the current progress: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBrzqz

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("http://www.honigwine.com/assets/images/global/tabs/arrow-down.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}
.search select {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 110%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search select .option {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <select>
    <option value="" class="option">Choose something</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Historically I believe it's been very tricky to style the `Option` HTML tag but CSS3 can do this, in moderation, in *most* browsers. There are also various Javascript plugins that do a good job of total input overhaul styling. Both of these are around on other questions on this topic.

Comment: That's a dupe for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last style in css hides the default dropdown aroow and shows only the custom one.

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("http://www.honigwine.com/assets/images/global/tabs/arrow-down.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}
.search select {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search select .option {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width:100%;
} 
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <select>
    <option value="" class="option">Choose something</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but this unfortunately also causes the default arrow to appear, but I wish to keep the custom one.

Comment: I took care of that and edited answer as soon as I posted it, can you please accept it now, thank you

Comment: that's it! I didn't know about this appearance attribute...thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is working with a pseudo element which contains your desired background image.

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}
.search:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa url("http://www.honigwine.com/assets/images/global/tabs/arrow-down.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}
.search select {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 110%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search select .option {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <select>
    <option value="" class="option">Choose something</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: this unfortunately causes the default arrow to appear, but I wish to keep the custom one

Answer (score 0):

Well there is one `option` of setting `appearance` to `none` in `select`, another you can set you `background position` and hide that select arrow by `img` at `top` as below,

```css
.search {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa url("http://www.honigwine.com/assets/images/global/tabs/arrow-down.png") no-repeat 100.4% 48%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
}

.search select {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search > select > .option {
    padding: 10px 18px;
        width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <select>
       <option value="" class="option">Choose something</option>
       <option value="">One</option>
       <option value="">Two</option>
       <option value="">Three</option>
     </select>
</div>
```